# How to call a Method in OnClickListener without variable (Fajr) in the method becoming null when called

Tags: java, android

In my OnClickListener:

```
private Button mPrayerTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPrayerTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
    mPrayerTime.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               cityModel cityObj= new cityModel();
                String fajr=cityObj.getFajr();
            Log.d("Fajr", ""+fajr);
        }
    });
}
```

I call a method called cityModel, found here

```
   public final class cityModel implements Serializable {
    private String fajr;



    public void setFajr(String fajr) {
        this.fajr= fajr;

    }
    public String getFajr() {

        return fajr;
    }
}
```

which retrieves set.Fajr from:

```
     protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        String[] prayers = {"fajr", "shurooq", "dhuhr", "asr", "maghrib", "isha"};
        final cityModel cityObj;
        try {
            cityObj= new cityModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cityObject =
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                result = result + "fajr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("fajr") + "\n" + result + "shurooq" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("shurooq") + "\n" + result + "dhuhr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("dhuhr") + "\n" + result + "asr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("asr") + "\n" + result + "maghrib" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("maghrib") + "\n" + result + "isha" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("isha") + "\n";

                cityObj.setFajr(""+cityObject.getString("fajr"));


            }
```

When I tried to debug, I found that cityModel finds the value for fajr and stores it just fine, so the issue seems to be with how I call the method because whenever I look for the label Fajr in logcat it shows up as null.

Comment: Please avoid using the wording "the variable" as it makes your question more difficult to understand. Instead, write the name of the particular variable that is null. This question takes a lot of re-reading just to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Well you are creating a new instance of your object and passing a string by using the getter method.

Comment: @Elliott Edited it.

Comment: @sarthakGandhi Exactly. So how do I call the method without creating a new instance??

Comment: You use the object in which you set the value.

Comment: @sarthakGandhi but when I call cityObj.getFajr() without calling a cityModel first (which I only know how to call by calling a new instance of it) it tells me that it is an unknown symbol

Comment: `cityModel cityObj = cityObj.getFajr();` How is this code possible when getFajr returns a String?

Comment: @Elliott Haha I don't know. It doesn't crash, just returns cityObj.getFajr as null. How should it be?

Comment: @Elliott Am wondering why this line is not throwing any compiler error?

Comment: @Sanoop I can run the app and copy paste the logcat if you want but I assure you it does run just does nothing

Comment: @Sanoop sorry, do you mean "I am wondering" or "are you wondering"

Comment: @Slothins It's impossible to debug your pasted code when it is syntactically invalid, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Elliott Theoretically then, what would be my next step?

Comment: @Slothins probably you pasted wrong; please correct your pasted code.

Comment: Dude, no wonder its not working, the object you are handling in onClick is a different object than the one in outputTimings. Also, please take extreme care to paste the correct code next time, I'm really being *very* nice by SO standards, and you are just wasting people's time if you paste wrong code and ask others to debug it.

Comment: @Elliott I appreciate you sticking with me on this :D. How do I call the original object instead of creating a new one?

Comment: use a member variable

Comment: @Elliott I looked that up and it seems to be what Im looking for! If you have any useful documentation you can point me to Id be much obliged!

Comment: also you must learn java from book or online course to understand before posting